# MatPaginator gets undefined

Tags: angular-material2

I have replicated thsi case:  [Angular 5 Material Table not getting data from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456808/angular-5-material-table-not-getting-data-from-service?answertab=oldest#tab-top][1])

But when I try access any property from paginator I get undefined error from this objet.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I got the same issue. Placing  mat-paginator tag outside *ngIf resolved my issue. Make sure it is available to component class without any conditions.

Comment: I remove the *ngIf condition and the problem persist. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I have other issue

Comment: Typeerror: unable to get property ‘nativeElement’ of undefined or null reference

Comment: Excellent solution. Good luck

Comment: This worked for me. However, i would like to do a conditional. Any ideas how to apply an ngIf?

Comment: this works for me too, when a load the data and the *ngif was activated that doesnt work, but i remove the *ngif and the code works!

Comment: @Logan_B use [hidden] instead of *ngIf

Comment: I had to fight all day long and it turned out to be the same problem. This solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 18):

Some issues that may cause mat-paginator is undefined:

1. You forgot to import in app.module.ts `import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';` and then declare the import in the imports array inside ngModule.

   @NgModule({ declarations: [ somestuff], imports: [ MatPaginatorModule]});
2. Import MatPaginator inside the component you are using: 
   `import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';`
3. set the MatDataSource to be none. (only need to do this if you are going to be getting async data e.g. from a server)

   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
4. Make sure you set the length property of the mat-paginator to the length of the data rows returned.
5. Set the paginator inside `NgAfterViewInit` method or if that doesn't work try:

private paginator: MatPaginator;
private sort: MatSort;

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
}

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
}

setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
        this.applyFilter('');
    }
}
```

Comment: When my pagination stopped working, point 5 is what fixed it for me. Thanks

Comment: ngAfterViewIniit did not work, but the code you shared did! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In some cases, the issue is related to conditional outer div. Ex:

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
    ...

   <mat-paginator ....>
</div>
```

For a such scenario just replace *ngIf="condition" with [hidden]="!condition" and it'll work.
Please refer to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205 for more details

Comment: [hidden]="!condition" is working. Don't use *ngIf

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and this is how I got it working:

**My Initial Code Setup**

**component.html**

```
    <div class="chart-wrapper" *ngIf="viewType === 'chart'; else table;">
        // Load Chart Here
    </div>

    <ng-template #table>
        // Load Table Here

        <mat-paginator
            #paginator
            [length]="tableDataSource.data ? tableDataSource.data.length : 0"
            [pageSize]="pageSize"
            [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
            (page)="onPageChange($event)"
        ></mat-paginator>
    </ng-template>
```

**component.ts**

```
columns: string[] = [];
tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]> = new MatTableDataSource([]);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
pageIndex = 0;
pageSize = 10;
pageSizeOptions = [10, 15, 20];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getTableData();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}

getTableData() {
    // After getting data from API
    this.tableDataSource.data = apiResponse;
}
```

**The Solution**

Put ***static: false*** while declaring Mat Paginator

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

and then set **paginator** onto **tableDataSource** after data gets loaded into it

```
this.tableDataSource.data = apiResponse;
this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

*Thanks to the solution by **cisco336*** [on this thread](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205)

To my surprise nobody appraised that solution.

Comment: The "static: false" was enough for me, question is why?

Answer (score 4):

For me it was broken after angular upgrade from 7 to any version(although i checked in only angular 12).
In Angular 8 they introduced a parameter where we are supposed to give {static: true} if we need the value in ngOninit. From Angular 9 it was set to false by default if we are not mentioning it explicitly.

So changing code from this
`@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`

To this
`@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;`

Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

"Inserting an *ngIf means that its contents cannot be queried until the view is initialized with change detection. This means the query for sort is empty at ngOnInit.

This can be resolved by changing the setup from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mewfek?file=src/app/app.component.ts "

reference 
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15966

Answer (score 2):

In my case, paginator object was getting initiated in ngOnInit() and giving exception paginator is undefined.

**Initial code i.e. not working code:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new StoreServiceDataSource<User>(this.userService, this.snackBar);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

**After correction i.e. working code:**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new StoreServiceDataSource<User>(this.userService, this.snackBar);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Just changed initializing life cycle hook. Earlier paginator was getting initialized in **hgOnInit()**, now it's initialized in **ngAfterViewInit().**

Answer (score 1):

[length]="dataSource.filteredData.length" over "mat-paginator" worked for me.

`<mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10,25,50]" #paginator [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length"[showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>`

Comment: please explain some more

Comment: Updated above comment, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

MatPaginator being undefined most likely means you do not have the module imported. Sometimes angular mat does not explicitly tell you these things that you are missing. But always check the `API` tab under their documentation before using a component. At your module level, you should have the following in your `app.module.ts` file.

the import

```
import { MatButtonModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
```

Your component imported that used paginator of course

```
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';
```

Those modules imported in your imports array

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    HttpClientModule
],
```

And those modules exported if necessary (different topic so I wont discuss here).

```
exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
],
```

This is all happening in my App.Module

```
export class AppModule { }
```

This assuming you do bot have your project structured as feature modules. In that case you would really only need everything I talked about in the module in which your component lives. But in this case, where everything is under the app module, this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="  fixed-form-bottom" [hidden]="changeState">
  <div class="team-footer">
    <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="pageSize" [showFirstLastButtons]="true" [length]="totalSize"
      [pageIndex]="currentPage" (page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)" [hidePageSize]="true">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in .ts file , you compare your condition and pass true/ false from there

```
if(this.totalSize>3){
  this.changeState=true;

}
```

its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `*ngIf` that wrap your mat-paginator or any top component, if you need hide you should use `[hidden]` attribute in your component

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the delay in pagination injection is one or more missing end tag such as  within your html markup, which seems to impact the timing of the pagination markup DOM injection.

In this type of problem scenario a 2nd+ load of the table will show the pagination components.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this problem

**Solution 1:**
If mat-paginator is inside *ngIf then either **take it outside** or use [hidden] attribute.

```
<div [hidden]="condition">
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**
Make sure you are not using `static: true` while initializing the paginator

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

change it to

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```