# Angular MatPaginator doesn`t get initialized

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I have 2 components. Both have mat-table and paginators and pagination is working for one component and not working for the other component though the code is similar. Below is my html:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="col1">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column1 </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.col1}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="col2">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column2 </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.col2}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Different columns goes here -->

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator #scheduledOrdersPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

And below is my code in component.ts:

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
displayedColumns = ['col1', 'col2', ... ];

@ViewChild('scheduledOrdersPaginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load data
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(somearray);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Similar code is working for the other component and table is getting rendered with the pagination properly, no clue what's wrong with this code.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I resolved a similar issue by surrounding the instantiation with a timeout. Try this :

```
setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
```

Comment: I know, I was flabbergasted too ! Well from my opinion, I think it's because the datasource isn't triggering a change detection when you set it, so you need to do it yourself. For that, you have either a timeout, or the use of the change detector (but the timeout is easier and faster to use)

Comment: No problem, if it bothers you, submit this issue to the material team on their github !

Comment: It's been a few months since this question, in case others come across it -- ngOnInit initialisation is working fine for me (in fact, my scenario has a level of indirection, table is wrapped in another component). For me this odd issue was caused by (mistakenly) sharing the same data source instance in the parent to child tables while playing around with some UI ideas. One can imagine it messes things up.

Comment: angular provides `ngAfterViewInit` for this

Comment: Not when you refresh your data source.

Comment: True. But again there is a whole other way of doing mat-table whenyou want to use live connection to databases. setTimeout is never a ba habit (lazy way out)

Comment: Yeah, setTimeout is the black swan of JS ... We must show it love

Comment: Instead of removing *ngIf="condition" you can just replace it with [hidden]="!condition" and like that angular will catch and initiate the paginator and sorting elements

Comment: This was a solution for me as well. However It didn't work first because I didn't put setTimeout for " this.dataSource.sort = this.sort "   I put another setTimeout and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This isn't really a solution but a hack. Anyone using this as the solution is taking a risk and doing it wrong.

Answer (score 178):

In my case, the `<mat-paginator>` element was inside a container that had an `*ngIf` on it, which did not render until the data loaded asynchronously. This causes `this.paginator` to be `undefined` even in `ngAfterViewInit`. This causes it to silently fail as `MatTableDataSource` has no problem with you setting `paginator` to `undefined`.

The solution was to move the `<mat-paginator>` outside of the `*ngIf`'d container

Hopefully, this helps someone who is in the same situation as me.

Comment: Thank you - this was the solution for me. I opted to use `[hidden]` instead of ngIf so that the paginator would render even if there wasn't any data, but wouldn't show up to the user

Comment: thank you so much, this solved it, was pulling my hair out because the same code had worked on an earlier component. The only difference here was that I was providing the data to a dumb component via @input rather then requesting the data onint.

Comment: My suggestion (answer) below works even then when the mat-table is surrounded by `NgIf.`

Answer (score 70):

Although selected answer works and solves the problem it is still a workaround. This is proper and more elegant way to deal with the problem.

Try adding `AfterViewInit` interface to your class, then put `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator` inside `ngAfterViewInit()` method

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
    }
```

then you would not have to call workaround `setTimeout`.

Comment: this is the more appropriate method

Comment: This does not work for me. My data source is being loaded after ngAfterViewInit which may be the problem. I tried initializing the data source first and then using ngAfterViewInit to set the paginator but it did not work. The only thing I found that worked was the workaround in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the solution for me. setTimeout works randomly. so I used this solution.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, too. what i did is reassign the paginator after my data gets loaded.

Answer (score 41):

**Angular  7+ (8/9/10/11/12)**
There is another elegant solution to solve that problem.

**Short Version**

Immediately after setting data source invoke `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

**Long Version**

**Step1:**

Import `ChangeDetectorRef` & Material related stuff

```js
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
```

**Step2:**

Set class-properties in your component

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

**Step3:**

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor

```js
constructor (..., private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ...) { ... }
```

**Step4:**

Set data source and invoke `detectChanges()`

```js
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource (MY_DATA);
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

**Optional Steps:**

After that, you can set other properties like

```js
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

Comment: works perfectly in Angular 9.1.2 when the mat-table is surrounded by ng-if

Comment: In what lifecycle event, should I set `dataSource` and invoke `deleteChanges` ?

Comment: „detectChanges“ not deleteChanges :) A special LiveCycle ist not necessary, just after assignmet of the datasource,..

Answer (score 31):

This is because of this.paginator is undefined at the time it going to assign to this.dataSource.paginator.

if you using static data this will work

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator; // For pagination
 @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort; // For Sort

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.dataSource.data = this.dataList; // Data list is data array 
 }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; // For pagination
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; // For sort
 }
```

if you using dynamic data (Data from API) this will work

For Pagination

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false})
  set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    if (this.dataSource){
      this.dataSource.paginator = value;
    }
  }
```

For Sort

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false})
  set sort(value: MatSort) {
    if (this.dataSource){
      this.dataSource.sort = value;
    }
  }
```

As a side note im using Angular 9 at the movement.

Comment: This solved my issue with having to use setTimeout(0 => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator).  Using angular 8

Comment: This is working for me Using angular 13.1.1

Comment: Thanks, it is working on Angular 12.2.16

Comment: ngAfterViewInit did the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot, spent some hours figuring out a clean way to make my server side (one time only) fetch of data work

Answer (score 22):

**1st Solution**

Move mat-paginator from inside *ngIf div to outside

**2nd Solution**

use static false while declaring MatPaginator or MatSort

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
```

Comment: Wow, the 2nd solution solved all of my table's problems: Pagination, Sort and Filter.

Comment: Sadly solution no.2 is only valid if the current Angular version is greater than 7.

Answer (score 20):

The question when the paginator is available in the view and can be retrieved and attached to the data source is the main crux of this issue and a common pitfall. Workarounds suggested here include using `setTimeout()` and `ngAfterViewInit`, are simply that - workarounds in the vein of "let's see how much we need to wait to make sure that the `@ViewChild` has set our component field with the correct paginator value".

The correct methodology is to attach the `@ViewChild` to a property setter and set the data source paginator as soon (and as often) as that setter is called with a valid paginator.

It is also very useful to have a single data source and not replace it every load (as I've seen many people do) - just bind a data source to the mat-table and update it's `data` field.

```html
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="col1">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column1 </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.col1}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="col2">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column2 </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.col2}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- additional columns go here -->

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator #scheduledOrdersPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource();
displayedColumns = ['col1', 'col2', ... ];

@ViewChild('scheduledOrdersPaginator') set paginator(pager:MatPaginator) {
  if (pager) this.dataSource.paginator = pager;
}

@ViewChild(MatSort) set sort(sorter:MatSort) {
  if (sorter) this.dataSource.sort = sorter;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData().subscribe(somearray => { this.dataSource.data = somearray; });
}
```

This approach should also solve the problem (noted by one of the commenters here) of having the paginator rendered late when hidden behind an `*ngIf` template - the paginator will be sent to the data source even if it gets rendered very late.

Answer (score 10):

To make it work I had to set the paginator after the data was fetched from source

```
getVariables() {
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params['id'] && (params['type'] === Type.CodeList)) {
            this.dataService
                .getItems(this.currentLanguage, params['id'])
                .subscribe((items: any) => {
                    this.dataSource.data = this.items;
                    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It took me hours to figure it out.

The key is `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyInterface>(Object.values(data));`
Then set `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`

I was using `this.dataSource = data` although I could get the data but the pagination was not working.

Again you have to use `new MatTableDataSource`

Works in Angular 11.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that I find is to to set the paginator after the data is successfully loaded.

```
this._empService.GetEmpList().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.empListDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<empToShow>(Object.values(data))
    this.empListDataSource.paginator = this.paginator
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

After trying all the above-provided solutions finally the simple solution worked for me. I am posting for reference if anyone stuck.

I am using Angular 8. Just add { static: false } in child reference

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

[Got Solution From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704164/angular-viewchild-error-expected-2-arguments-but-got-1)

I was using this :

<strike>@ViewChild(MatSort, { read: true, static: false }) sort: MatSort;</strike>

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { read: true, static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

Comment: `static: false` is the default setting - you shouldn't need to set it.

Answer (score 4):

None  of the above solution worked for me.

I figured out what was the issue, mainly `this.paginator` will be undefined until the table is loaded and in view, that's why in some of the in places `setTimeout` solution works.

But in my case, my table was hidden behind some `ngIf` logic  so the the table was only loaded after the `ngIf` becomes true(which happens on user interaction ) , but I was setting `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator` on `ngOnInit`

So, the solution depends on your case, the ground truth is make sure the table is loaded only then `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator`

I resolved it by, when user does the interaction and `ngIf` becomes `true` after that I call a function  to set the paginator

```
     initPaginator(){
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am quite a beginner in angular and typescript, but after having the same problem (except, that for me sorting didn't work either), what helped was creating a function '`refreshDataScource()`' and having it called from `ngAfterViewInit()` as well as after each time the server responds with new data. In this function I simply refresh the `dataSource` with the paginator and the sort. Like this:

```
refreshDataSource() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myDataArray);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

It fixed the paginator and the sort. Everything works now perfectly. However I am not sure if it is just a workaround or a real fix.

Answer (score 3):

Using **setTimeOut()** will solve the issue temporarily, however, this will again fail to  work if you are pushing a huge load of Data [say 1000 rows] into MatDataSource.

we've found that the MatTable loads very slowly if a large data set is set before you set the data-source paginator.

```
ngOninit(){
// initialize dataSource here
}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  /* now it's okay to set large data source... */
  this.dataSource.data = [GetLargeDataSet];}
```

So, initialize the data-Source at first place and set the properties like "Paginator" or "Sort" before pushing the data into the source into the "Data" property.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to do implement what Lonely suggested, regarding ChangeDetectorRef, and also, set an object with static: false, in the @ViewChild, like this:

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: any // For pagination
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: any; // For Sort
```

use like this it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As the most voted answer mentions, it is due to a conflict caused by *ngIf:

SOLUTIONS:

1. Leave the mat-paginator out of the *ngIf conditional.
2. Change the *ngIf conditional to something else that suits your needs.

   2.1 You can replace it with [hidden]="conditional".

   2.2 You can also use [ngClass]="'d-none': conditional", and create a class that contains display: none.

There are others but personally the one I use when it causes this type of inconvenience is 2.2

Comment: Leaving the mat-paginator out of the *ngIf conditional worked for me! Of course, be aware to initialize the pagination properly (i.e., length, size, page index, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This took me *hours* to finally track down and understand why my table wasn't working. Placing some console.logs() helped me figure out the order of events and why it didn't work consistently. My scenario was similar to the original issue above with a dynamic data source, but slightly different. For me, when I would first refresh my angular app, the paginator state would be set and then the data for my table would be set. When these events would happen in the this order the paginator worked just as expected.

Because I was using ReplaySubjects for getting the data for my tables, my paginator state would be set in **ngAfterViewInit** and then the table data would come in from my subscription (it depends on user ID so I don't have an initial value and that is why I didn't use BehaviorSubjects). My problem was that, when I would navigate to another component in my app, and return to my dynamic table data source, the table data would be set before the paginator state. This would make the paginator show page x, but the displayed data would always be the first page of data.

To fix this annoying issue I:

1. Wrote a simple function for setting my table data as someone mentioned above:

```js
  setTableData() {
    // set table data
    this.tableData.data = this.images.filter(img => this.filterData(img));

    // some other code below
    ....
  }
```

2. Added two flags in my component, one for if I had loaded the table data and one for if my pagination state had been set. This way I could ensure that the pagination state is set before the data.

```js
  // initialize our data source for our table and set flags for state
  tableData = new MatTableDataSource<IImage>(this.images);
  loading = true;
  setPageState = false;
```

3. Added a setTimeout to ngAfterViewInit which would set my paginator state and set my table data only if the table data came through **before** ngAfterViewInit was called. The setTimeout prevents the annoying "expression changed after value was checked" error.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // add pagination state to our table
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Set paginator state');
      this.setPageState = true;
      this.paginator.pageIndex = this.state.pageIndex;

      // check if we are not loading data, meaning the table came in first so
      // we need to set the data here
      if (!this.loading) {
        this.setTableData();
      }
    }, 0);
  }
```

4. Lastly, in ngOnInit, where I subscribe to my data, I **do not** set my table data unless the paginator state was set first:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.tableData.sort = this.sort;
    this.tableData.paginator = this.paginator;

    // listen for data
    this.dbService.images.subscribe(images => {
      console.log('Data subscription');
      // save images
      this.images = images;

      // only set table data if paginator state has been set, otherwise it doesnt work
      if (this.setPageState) {
        this.setTableData();
      }

      // hide spinner and update that we have data
      this.loading = false;
    });

    // other code
    .....
  }
```

And with that, my pagination was finally working consistently for when I first login to the app and when I navigate to other pages and go back to my dynamic table.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <mat-paginator
        #scheduledOrdersPaginator
          (page)="pageEvent($event)">
        </mat-paginator>
         pageEvent(event){
         //it will run everytime you change paginator
           this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          }
```

Comment: You need some descriptive text about why this is a good solution, and perhaps some comment(s) on the original source.

Answer (score 1):

Only change

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
```

for

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
displayedColumns = ['col1', 'col2', ... ];
@ViewChild('scheduledOrdersPaginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load data
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(somearray);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (table data displaying but MatPaginator is not working).
**In my case, I forgot to create  "new MatTableDataSource"**

```
this.dataSource = somearray;
```

not enable MatPaginator while `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(somearray);` does.

extract from [material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#features)

"To simplify the use case of having a table **that can sort, paginate, and filter an array of data**, the Angular Material library comes with a **MatTableDataSource** that has already implemented the logic of determining what rows should be rendered according to the current table state."

hope this answer helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I added reference  ***scheduledOrdersPaginator*** into pagintaor tag and received with **@ViewChild**. It solved my pagination problem. Below code may help others.

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
displayedColumns = ['col1', 'col2', ... ];
@ViewChild('scheduledOrdersPaginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load data
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(somearray);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

html:

```
<mat-paginator #scheduledOrdersPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons> </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: What is the background of this resolution ? it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To paginate the table's data, add a `<mat-paginator>` after the table.

If you are using the MatTableDataSource for your table's data source, simply provide the MatPaginator to your data source. It will automatically listen for page changes made by the user and send the right paged data to the table.

Otherwise if you are implementing the logic to paginate your data, you will want to listen to the paginator's (page) output and pass the right slice of data to your table.

For more information on using and configuring the `<mat-paginator>`, check out the mat-paginator docs.

The MatPaginator is one provided solution to paginating your table's data, but it is not the only option. In fact, the table can work with any custom pagination UI or strategy since the MatTable and its interface is not tied to any one specific implementation.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

See also
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: all the solutions were not working, because <mat-paginator> should be added after the table. as you mentioned at the start of your answer and it worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using setTimeout() is only a viable solution when you know how much time it will take to load the table. My problem was I using an *ngIf on the table (with !isLoading):

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.rawData);

this.initPaginator();

this.isLoading = false;
```

The fix was setting my isLoading variable to false only after change detections and initializing the paginator:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.rawData);

this.isLoading = false;

this.cdr.detectChanges();

this.initPaginator();
```

So it loads the data -> shows the table -> detects changes -> inits paginator.
I hope this helps anyone!

Comment: I don't usually use setTimeout and I want to be avoiding until I can't do without it. To execute cdr.detectChanges() before setting paginator on dataSource has worked for me. I have a component which use OnPush strategy and dynamic setting data from outside by the way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

for Angular version below 7, use `read` argument for MatPaginator.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {read: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

this worked for me.

Note that this works for Dynamically loaded table data.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
   this.sort = ms;
   this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
   this.paginator = mp;
   this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
   if(this.dataSource !== undefined){
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   }
  }
```

Comment: try using this piece of code for dynamic dataSource and for the table placed inside ng-container using ng-if. No need to use [hidden] with div's.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this, with `mat-paginator` inside a container with a `ngIf`.

The only thing that worked for me was the comment:

> Thank you - this was the solution for me. I opted to use [hidden] instead of ngIf so that the paginator would render even if there wasn't any data, but wouldn't show up to the user – [TabsNotSpaces](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4705727/tabsnotspaces)

To clarify, what I did was create a `div`, outside the container, with `[hidden]=<negation_of_the_same_condition_as_the_ngIf>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **async-await** worked for me inside **ngOnInit()**, the paginator and sort has to wait!

```
   @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
   @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; 
    .
    .
    .
   ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._statsService.getAllCampgrounds().subscribe(
      async (response) => {
        this.allCampgrounds = response.allCampgrounds;
        this.dataSource = await new MatTableDataSource(this.allCampgrounds);
        
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the anwsers posted above helped me in this case.

The reason why my pagination didn't work depsite correct implementation was import

e.x.

```
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";
```

didn't work, so I changed this component import to

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue, As I had two mat tables with mat paginators and only one of them works. I tried all of the above options, then I realized I was updating the datasource object instead of datasource.data, didn't realized that I was updating the type, thanks to @Bigeyes for sharing his answer.

Table loading data but paginator not working:

```
this.datasource = data.filter(x => (x.planName == this.planName && x.Termed_y == 1))
```

Table loading data and paginator working:

```
this.dataSource2.data = data.filter(x => (x.planName == this.planName && x.Termed_y == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using `setTimeout` is to use `set` :

```js
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;


 set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Comment: This solution, just by the code written, wouldn't work - nothing is calling the `matPaginator` property: Angular will set the `paginator` property and so the `dataSource.paginator` will remain unset.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, data coming from service asynchronously so neither could use ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit, I used ngOnChanges, something like below:

```js
ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges) {
    if (change.properties) {
      if (this.properties.length > 0) {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.properties);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
    }
  }
```

Be sure to set the [DataSource] attribute at mat-table element at html to the data source property from the component so to ensure the data source get bind with the table and paginator.

Answer (score 0):

Do check out this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47670333/7173194).

Setting the paginator in typescript after HTML components getting loaded (***ngIf**) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported the `MatPaginatorModule` in the `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just add the property MatPaginator.length.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="Elements.length"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Added the following to resolve it.

Step1
Add ChangeDetectorRef to constructor
E.g

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Step2
call detect change method and pagination in the init method

```
this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```