# Angular material matpaginator not displayig data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create data table in Angular 8.
But paginator below data table is not working. There are 10 hard coded records in my component. When I select 5/10 elements per page, result is not changing. The buttons next to it are also greyed out.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

export class AppComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Maybe the answer to this similar question could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785965/angular-matpaginator-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the controller implemented?

**.html**

```
    <input matInput [ngModel]="pageSizeOptions" (ngModelChange)="setPageSizeOptions($event)"
         [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" placeholder="Ex. 10,25,50">
```

**.ts**

```
    setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    if (setPageSizeOptionsInput) {
      this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding this.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { ... }`