# angular material pagination and sorting issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been looking for a solution to this issue but unfortunately couldn't make it work. I followed the official angular material guide and wrote the following code, which is supposed to support pagination and sorting of the material table:

```
export class RecentAnnouncementsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['created_utc', 'name', 'title'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  items: ItemData[] = [];

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getItems().subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result;
      this.dataSource.data = this.items;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

The following error persists:

> Property 'paginator' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned
> in the constructor.

I tried to modify the code according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785965/angular-matpaginator-not-working?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) answers but nothing worked. At most, I got rid of errors but the pagination and sorting buttons didn't affect the table items.

I would be very thankful for a suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: Try adding `@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;`

Comment: this worked: @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're working on the latest version of Angular. I do, and I got this working with:

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort = new MatSort();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator = new MatPaginator(new MatPaginatorIntl(), ChangeDetectorRef.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this to solve:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort = <MatSort>{};
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator = <MatPaginator>{};
```

This way also works:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort | null = null;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator | null = null;
```